# "I was used", is it correct?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, colloquialisms

I want to use the term *used*, like ***I was used***. I mean when someone used my name or some of my property for his own advantage.

Is it OK to say in this context: *I was used* ?

Comment: That's entirely wrong, @MamtaDalal

Comment: @itsbruce Could you tell me why it is wrong?

Comment: I mean someone used my name for his advantage. Not i used my money or my property.

Comment: You haven't understood what Nwe is asking, @MamtaDalal .  "Someone used my name or some of my property for his advantage".  He wants to describe somebody else defrauding him or committing a similar crime.

Comment: @matma Because it's completely contrary to the intent and examples  of the original question. In Nwe's example, *he* is not using *anything*. It is *someone else* who is making use of Nwe's property. Therefore, Nwe himself *cannot* say "I used..." anything (because, in his examples, he's used *nothing*).

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Thanks. But even then "I was used" is wrong. Should be "my name was used" or something similar.

Comment: @Matma, Except that ignores the English idiom "*I was used*" (as in "*He **used** me*").

Answer (score 3):

**"I was used"** is perfectly good English but may not have quite the meaning you are looking for.  It is quite a common phrase in crime thrillers and soap operas, where it is used to convey the meaning **"I, as a person, was used.  I was tricked into doing or believing X, when the deceiver only wanted to take advantage of me.  I feel exploited and cheapened."**

If somebody else used your name (that is, signed cheques or legal papers with your name, or pretended to be you while performing some other activity) without your knowledge, that is "Identity theft".  If somebody has stolen your identity, you probably will feel **used**, as described in my first paragraph, but to say "I was used" is to talk about the personal impact it had on you and how it has made you feel, not to describe precisely what was done to you.  "My identity was stolen" describes the act.

Comment: Upvoted since your answer now makes sense. I see where I was wrong.

Comment: @Nwe, you're on a site full of English pedants, grammar nazis, and orthographic prescriptivists. At the bottom of the viper pit, as it were. It would be better all around if you expanded "*ur*" to "*your*" (*a distant rattling sound is heard*).

Comment: Ok, I won't use "ur" anymore, Thanks @Dan

Answer (score 2):

*Use* can mean

> to treat someone in an unfair way, for example by pretending to care
>   about them so that they do what you want
>
> *You know he's just using you.*
>
> use someone for your own ends (=to get what you want):
>
> *Liz has always used people for her own ends.*
>
> http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/use#use_17

In that sense, you can say "I was used". I don't think it's appropriate if someone stole your credit card and obtained money and/or goods for themselves. That person is not *using* you. However, if they make you fall in love with them and persuade you to buy things for them on the basis of the mistaken belief that they care for you, then they are *using* you.